# BIRT: Alternating row Color in a table group

Tags: reporting, birt

Has anybody an idea of how the highlighting condition has to look like, to create alternating rows in groups? I want the every row with an even number of a table group (not of the whole table) to have a different color.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Patrick

P.S.: I'm using BIRT 2.1.3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a highlight to the row like this:

```
row[0] % 2 Equals 0
```

This works because row is the current row and row[0] is the rownumber. row[1], row[2] etc. are the data values for the current row.

(Source: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.birt/msg03977.html)

Answer (score 10):

For Birt 2.3 reporting

Click on the table from the outline view. The on the properties editor, clikc the Highlight tab. Click Add. You will see three drop downs. Just type row.__rownum % 2 in the first drop down. Select the Equal to from the second and then type 0 in the third. Then you set the background color of the row to whatever color you want most times I use silver.

Hit ok and thats all.

Comment: You don't click on the table but on the row of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Total.runningCount()%2 Equals 0