# BIRT Alternate Row Color Reset in each Group

Tags: report, designer, birt

I'm trying to highlight (silver background color) alternate rows in a BIRT report which has groups.  Although I have implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576941/birt-alternating-row-color-in-a-table-group)  the problem is that each group does not always start with a highlighted row.  I want the highlighting rows reset for each group.

The way it is now:

```
Department A
  Highlight
  not highlight
  Highlight

Department B
  not highlight
  Highlight
```

What I want is:

```
Department A
  Highlight
  not highlight
  Highlight

Department B
  Highlight
  not highlight
```

Is there any way to acheive this?

I am using BIRT 4.2.2 and the dataset is a single sql query, grouped by department.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is similar to the one linked, but additionally you need to define a running count of rows within a group.

To do so:

- In the report designer Layout view, select the whole table (by clicking just below the bottom of the report on the left hand side).
- In the Property Editor for the Table, select the Binding tab.
- In the Binding tab, click the `Add Aggregation...` button (on the right) and enter the following options:

  - Column Binding Name: something meaningful (such as `groupRow`);
  - Data Type: Integer;
  - Function: RUNNINGCOUNT;
  - Aggregate On: Group (and select the appropriate group).

Then amend the highlighting expression for the row to be:

```
row["groupRow"] % 2 Not Equal to 0
```

(instead of `row[0] % 2 Equals 0`.)

If you now preview the report, you should find the odd-numbered rows within each group highlighted, as required.