# birt report generic style for all rows in table

Tags: birt

I am trying to create a generic style for all rows in my data table. I have been looking around and there seems to be a function I can use named rownum.

I tired to create the style like this...

row["__rownum"] Less than 0

then colour = Red

But this is not right. Can someone tell me the right way to do this so I can apply the style to multiple cells in my table.

Also where can i find documentation on what sort of functions like this are available?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know two ways how you can specify conditional styles in BIRT:

You can write an "onRender" eventHandler (either in Java or JavaScript) for your row. In JavaScript it could looks as follow:

```
    if (row["__rownum"] % 2 == 0) {
      this.getStyle().backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
      this.getStyle().color = "red";
    }
```

Or create a new BIRT style with a highlight-rule like follows:

```
    row["__rownum"] % 2 equals to 0 then 
    Set Color or whatever or apply another style
```

Instead of creating a new style, that you will have to assign to target elements, you can also modify one of the predefined styles, if you find a one matching your targets.

Both EventHandler and Styles can be assigned to various element: Cells, Rows, Tables, Report...

Links you may find helpful:

- https://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportScripting.php
- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc.isv%2Fmodel%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fbirt%2Freport%2Fmodel%2Fapi%2FElementFactory.html
- [BIRT: Alternating row Color in a table group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576941/birt-alternating-row-color-in-a-table-group)

Comment: thanks Vlad. Appreciate the help. What you have posted is exactly what I have tried already. I will have to read some of your links to find out what i have done wrong